# cannot get paragraph with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

I have this piece of html:

```html
<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:12.0pt'><span style='font-size:8.5pt;
font-family:"Arial",sans-serif;mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>1. A
következő feldolgozása szükséges: <br>
<br>
1000806457 bevásárlókosár kiegészítése 107,28 EUR értékkel <br>
<br>
Kattintson a következő nyomógombra a rendszerbe való bejelentkezéshez és online
engedélyezéshez: <br>
<a
href="%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20https:/cip7a.reh.rehau.de:8431/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/ui2/ushell/shells/abap/FioriLaunchpad.html?sap-client=100#ShoppingCartItem-approve                                                                                                                              ">Bejelentk.
</a><br>
<br>
2. Áttekintés 1000806457, XXX 26.10.2021 11:03 sz. bevásárlókosárhoz <o:p></o:p></span></p>
```

I tried several ways to get this text: '2. Áttekintés 1000806457, XXX 26.10.2021 11:03 sz. bevásárlókosárhoz', fe. with this code:

```
var HTMLPList = from p in htmlEmail.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p[contains(@style,'margin-bottom:12.0pt')]").Cast<HtmlNode>()
                              select new { pText = p.InnerText };
```

But I get always null error. So, the question is: how to get the text above? I tried some 'contains' method, where the text contains 'Áttekintés', but no success.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you are not specifically looking for a xpath, here is one with css selectors (which is what I am used working with):

You want the last text node type within the child nodes of the paragraph element.

```
    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(@"<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:12.0pt'>
                        <span style=""font-size:8.5pt; font-family:'Arial',sans-serif;mso-fareast-font-family:'Times New Roman'"">
                            1. A következő feldolgozása szükséges: <br>
                            <br>
                            1000806457 bevásárlókosár kiegészítése 107, 28 EUR értékkel<br>
                            <br>
                            Kattintson a következő nyomógombra a rendszerbe való bejelentkezéshez és online
                            engedélyezéshez: <br>
                            <a href= '%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20https:/cip7a.reh.rehau.de:8431/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/ui2/ushell/shells/abap/FioriLaunchpad.html?sap-client=100#ShoppingCartItem-approve                                                                                                                              ' > Bejelentk.
                            </a><br>
                            <br>
                            2.Áttekintés 1000806457, XXX 26.10.2021 11:03 sz.bevásárlókosárhoz<o:p></o:p>
                        </span>
                  </p>");


    //Using HtmlAgilityPack.CssSelectors.NetCore
    var p = doc.QuerySelector("p span")
        .ChildNodes
        .Where(c => c.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Text && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.InnerText.Trim()))
        .LastOrDefault();
    
    Console.WriteLine(p.InnerText.Trim());
```